# Django: use related_name to create a subclass

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

How can I be able to use `related_name` to create a child model when the parent model is being created.

```py
from django.db import models

from django.db.models.signals import pre_save, post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver


class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    child = models.ForeignKey(Child, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="parent_child", null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save()

@receiver(post_save, sender=Parent)
def post_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs)
    if not instance.child:
        instance.child.parent_child.create(name="I am a child")


class Child(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

Currently, on save, I get a `NoneType` error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'parent_child'
```

These are the local variables in my stack trace

```
args: ()

instance: <Parent: asdf - asd-47013855>

kwargs:
{
 'created': True,
 'raw': False,
 'signal': <django.db.models.signals.ModelSignal object at 0x7f20b92e2ce0>,
 'update_fields': None,
 'using': 'default'
}

sender: <class 'parent.models.Parent'>
```

Comment: You're trying to create an object inside `save()` method of `Parent` which means you're trying to create child before parent is created

Comment: Makes sense, what is the correct / recommended way to go about it? Can I use a `post_save` receiver?

Comment: You can use [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/signals/#signals)

Comment: @AnkitTiwari updated my question to include `signals`. I still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to perform action on `NoneType` object eg. `instance.child`
because when you create your `Parent` instance you've to assing child to your `Parent.child` attribute so by default it will `None` so to assign child to your `Parent` class you can do like this & you don't require signals you can do this inside your save method.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()
    child = models.ForeignKey(Child, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="parent_child", null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.child:
           self.child = Child.objects.create(name="I am a child")
        super(Parent, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

also you're trying to access related object in wrong way if you're inside Parent you can access child directly using `Parent.child` & if you want to access `Parent` from `Child` then you can do like this `Child.parent_child` read more about [backward relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward)

Comment: you miss if self.child is None: , except that evrything is OK

Comment: He is trying to create child when Parent is created so by default child will be None

Comment: yes, but your save overrides child with new evrytime Parent is saved(even when only edited)

Answer (score 0):

```
def post_save_receiver(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs)
    if not instance.child:
        child = Child(name='I am a child').save()
        instance.child = child
        instance.save()
```